# animate fill of an SVG using anime.js (or will i have to change the fill to be something else ?)

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, anime.js

I have an SVG who's stroke i am animating useing anime.js like so:

```
$(function() {

  var lineDrawing = anime({
    targets: '#layer1 path',
    strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    duration: 1500,
    delay: function(el, i) {
      return i * 250
    },
    direction: 'alternate',
    loop: true
  });

});
```

My SVG is below:

```
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" viewBox="0 0 195.22488 193.54251" version="1.1" id="svg8" inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371" sodipodi:docname="star.svg">
        <defs
            id="defs2" />
        <sodipodi:namedview
            id="base"
            pagecolor="#ffffff"
            bordercolor="#666666"
            borderopacity="1.0"
            inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
            inkscape:pageshadow="2"
            inkscape:zoom="0.35"
            inkscape:cx="-99.713793"
            inkscape:cy="369.29872"
            inkscape:document-units="mm"
            inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
            showgrid="false"
            inkscape:snap-to-guides="true"
            inkscape:window-width="1366"
            inkscape:window-height="705"
            inkscape:window-x="-8"
            inkscape:window-y="-8"
            inkscape:window-maximized="1"
            fit-margin-top="0"
            fit-margin-left="0"
            fit-margin-right="0"
            fit-margin-bottom="0" />
        <metadata
            id="metadata5">
            <rdf:RDF>
            <cc:Work
                rdf:about="">
                <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                <dc:type
                    rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                <dc:title></dc:title>
            </cc:Work>
            </rdf:RDF>
        </metadata>
            <g
                inkscape:label="Layer 1"
                inkscape:groupmode="layer"
                id="layer1"
                transform="translate(-9.3736792,-53.001107)"
                fill="none" 
                fill-rule="evenodd" 
                stroke="currentColor" 
                stroke-width="5"
                >
                <path
                    sodipodi:type="star"
                    style="fill:#d4ff2a"
                    id="path10"
                    sodipodi:sides="5"
                    sodipodi:cx="111.125"
                    sodipodi:cy="155.6369"
                    sodipodi:r1="97.857147"
                    sodipodi:r2="48.928574"
                    sodipodi:arg1="0.81271377"
                    sodipodi:arg2="1.4410323"
                    inkscape:flatsided="false"
                    inkscape:rounded="0"
                    inkscape:randomized="0"
                    d="m 178.40476,226.69642 -60.94839,-22.54231 -53.122401,37.42824 2.604927,-64.93132 -52.012102,-38.95644 62.558327,-17.58745 20.977149,-61.504647 36.05825,54.061687 64.97669,0.94447 -40.27311,50.99941 z"
                    inkscape:transform-center-x="3.9129994"
                    inkscape:transform-center-y="-5.5444732" />
            </g>
        </svg>
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/146980/)** , I went through the doc's and there are examples on how to animate the stroke of an SVG, but what i really want to do is animate the fill of the SVG, I.E. animate the fill from the bottom to up. How do i do this ?

I have gone through the [doc's](http://animejs.com/documentation/#lineDrawing) but i don't see much of a clue.

**EDIT :-** To simplify my question, how exactly would i have to modify my SVG to animate the fill(or maybe i have to modify the fill to be something else) to move from downwards to up ?

Comment: You really need to first think about what it is you want to animate. "Animate the fill" would be understood in the sense of "Animate the paint server", which could be a solid color, a gradient or a pattern. What is it that you want to go "from the bottom to up"? Solid colors have no directional component. Patterns are positioned and sized in two dimensions. A linear gradient consists of stops distributed along a line, a radial gradient defines distances from a center. Or do you want to reveal an initially hidden object? Then maybe you want to animate the position/size of a clip path or mask?

Comment: @ccprog Thanks makes sense , edited my question , i think the gradient might be a solution ! but i'd prefer a anime.js solution :)

Comment: You still haven't really said what you want to happen. Do you want to change the color? Do you want to change the appearance of a color gradient, by changing the positon or changing the colors of the stops? Do you want to change the area where a color is shown (as opposed to it being "empty")?

Comment: What is the animation you are looking for? There is infinite ways to paint inside a polygon. Could you at least post an effect that you want to imitate?

Comment: @ibowankenobi exactly the one posted by taki , but done in anime.js

Answer (score 3):

you can add a `<linear gradient>` and animate its `<stop>`s ( without the library ), check  [animate svg gradients](https://designmodo.com/animate-svg-gradients/) for more details.

```js
$(function() {

  var lineDrawing = anime({
    targets: '#layer1 path',
    strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    duration: 1500,
    delay: function(el, i) {
      return i * 250
    },
    direction: 'alternate',
    loop: true
  });

});
```

```css
.svg__holder {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="layer1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox='0 0 850 800'> 

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="bottom-to-top" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(212, 255, 42)">
        <animate dur="5s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff">
        <animate dur="5s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
 
  <path class="path" stroke="#000000" fill="url(#bottom-to-top)" stroke-width="3" opacity="1"  d="m 178.40476,226.69642 -60.94839,-22.54231 -53.122401,37.42824 2.604927,-64.93132 -52.012102,-38.95644 62.558327,-17.58745 20.977149,-61.504647 36.05825,54.061687 64.97669,0.94447 -40.27311,50.99941 z" id="svg_1" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to define the background as a pattern instead of using a fill color. I don't know anime.js but I think it should be pretty simple to manipulate the x and y values of the background as well.

Using your jsfiddle:
.. define background:

```
    <defs
            id="defs2" />
            <pattern id="background" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="500" height="500" > <rect fill="#0000FF" x="0" y="150" width="500" height="500"> </image> </pattern>
...
</defs>
```

.. set background:

```
<path
                    sodipodi:type="star"
                    style="fill: url(#background)"
                    id="path10"
...
</path>
```

Here is an example: `https://jsfiddle.net/z8ok9osg/`

Comment: please ignore the image tag in my pattern: https://jsfiddle.net/z8ok9osg/2/